# Exporting video from Sibelius using ManuScript

Tags: sibelius

Context: I have a role as an assistant librarian in a TTBB choir.
We export each as a video as I do this by opening each file, triple clicking on the part, going to the file export video menu, change the output to HD, press the export button.

We have a lot of songs ... I'd like to automate that procedure.

How do you export video from Sibelius using either the command line (MacOSX) or using ManuScript?

I'm looking for an example that I can expand upon.

Comment: Have you looked at Apple's Script Editor that comes with Mac OS X? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript_Editor

Comment: Interesting idea @piiperi. Sibelius MacOSX does have a scripting dictionary. Looks like there is no explicit support for exporting but the UX could be scripted.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, you can use Apple's Script Editor, the Sibelius scripting language, or Automator, to automate the export process on Mac OS X.